# How much recovery can players do during a downtime scene?

Tags: healing, stress, cortex-prime

The Cortex Prime handbook is a bit vague about recovering multiple complications/stress during downtime scenes. Here's what seems clear:

- A player can only attempt to recover a particular complication once per scene: "If you beat the difficulty and the effect die is equal to or smaller than the complication, the complication is stepped down by one. You can't try to recover that complication again until time passes" (p 38).
- Each type of stress is automatically stepped down by one during a downtime scene. The player can attempt to recover the rest of the stress using the same rules as complications (p 40).
- It is possible, at least in some rulesets, for PCs to help each other recover stress. In TRACE 2.0, "Stress can be recovered in a scene shared with a second PC if that PC's player succeeds at a test with a difficulty that includes the stress die to be recovered" (p 167). This test has essentially the same rules as a player testing to recover their own stress.

Here's what I think can be inferred from the above:

- A player can attempt to recover *each* of their complications once per downtime scene. The recovery rules say "You can't try to recover *that* complication again until time passes," which implies you *can* try to recover other complications.
- A player can, additionally, attempt to recover *each* type of stress once per downtime scene. The rules say that stress, after being stepped down once, is recovered in the same way as complications are, which implies that each type of stress should be treated like a separate complication.

**Are these inferences correct?**

Secondly, I'm still not sure what this means for players testing to recover each other's stress. Which of the following scenarios is correct? (Arranged in order from most powerful to least powerful.)

- A player can help *each* other player recover *each* type of stress: Alice tests to recover her own stress. Then she tests to recover Bob's Injured stress, tests again for Bob's Exhausted stress, etc.; then she tests for Charlie's Injured stress, again for Charlie's Exhausted stress, etc. Bob and Charlie do the same for her and for each other.
- A player can help *one* other player recover *each* type of stress: Alice tests to recover her own stress. Then she tests to recover Bob's Injured stress, tests again for Bob's Exhausted stress, etc. She cannot help Charlie in this scene. Bob does the same for Charlie, and Charlie does the same for Bob.
- A player can help *one* other player recover *one* type of stress: Alice tests to recover her own stress. Then she tests to recover Bob's Injured stress. She cannot recover any other types of stress for Bob and cannot help Charlie in this scene. Charlie tests to recover Bob's Exhausted stress; Bob tests to recover Alice's Injured stress.
- A player can attempt to recover each type of stress once, *either* for themselves *or* for another player: Alice tests to recover her own Injured stress, Bob's Exhausted stress, and Charlie's Afraid stress. She cannot recover her own Exhausted stress or Bob's Injured stress in this scene. Bob and Charlie test to recover some combination of their own and others' stress.

**Do the rules specify, or is it up to the GM to decide how recovering others' stress should work?**